# Does SSRS dynamically set the alignment of table cells based on the majority of cell types in the column?

Tags: reporting-services

This is the first time I've run into this, but it appears that SSRS is setting the text-align to one value for all cells based on the type of the majority of the cells in the column.  This doesn't happen in BIDS, only in the report viewer, but it was reproducible on two different servers.

I have cells being set with either a dataset item of type System.Double or to the textual value of "--" when Is Nothing evaluates to true `=Iif(Fields!SLF.Value Is Nothing, "--", Fields!SLF.Value)`.  I never noticed before that if the majority of the cells in the column are Nothing, then the few that aren't Nothing get aligned to the left along with all of the "--" text items.  And now I also see columns where the opposite is also true, where if the majority of the cells in the column are numeric values, then everything is aligned right, even the few "--" text items in the column.  I'm only using Default TextAlign and VerticalAlign, and no Indent, SpaceAfter or SpaceBefore, nor any concatenated text or embedded preserved spaces.

Has anyone else in the SSRS universe seen this, and does anyone know why or have a good workaround for it?  Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen anything like that, but just specify the text-align for your cells, and SSRS will abide by your decision.

Comment: @TabAlleman, I thought that I had done that by using just the Default TextAlign property value, not realizing that this would then cause a single alignment type to be used for all values in the column.  I thought SSRS would intime check the values type and determine what "Default" meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using the Default TextAlign property value doesn't work.  SSRS does not seem to check intime the values type (when multiple types are used in the column.)  I'm only guessing that it uses some other algo to determine which alignment to use based on what the majority of types are in a column.  But one way to work around it that I've found is to explicitly set the TextAlign based on the same expression used to set the value, and this seems to work as I was expecting the property to.  So, if the value is set like this: `=Iif(Fields!SomeField.Value Is Nothing, "--", Fields!SomeField.Value`

Then set the TextAlign similarly with this: `=Iif(Fields!SomeField.Value Is Nothing, "Default", "Default"`

This works perfectly now, with text left aligned and numeric values right aligned (en-US region).